# binding events in jquery to replaced html

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a jquery plugin for use in my projects in editing items in a table. When a user clicks on an item to edit, I do a pop-up form where they then save the data. When the save is successful I return the new data as a html row and replace the old row with this new returned row, but then I have to rebind the events. I can't figure out how to do this in a generic way in jquery. I am not sure if using .live() in a plug in is also good practice or if it will always work.

Currently I'm calling a call back function to rebind the events which then needs to happen on each page where I want to use it, I would like the plug in to do this for me instead.

Comment: live works and it is the solution in your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery live() will work in your situation.

it's detailed documentation can be found out below -

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you won't have any other choice than using the live or delegate function. Any new DOM element won't be recognize otherwise.

As you can see http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/, they both

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future**.